# Can I just see if user is authenticated from Microsoft without saving credentials info in Cookies

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am using Microsoft authentication for user but I don't want to keep the user credentials to be saved in cookies so that it should ask every time performing a particular action in application.

I have created a simple web app with external authentication from Microsoft but when a user gets signed in it doesn't ask user for credentials from second time and redirect to RedirectUrl directly because user information is already there in Cookies. Normally this behavior looks fine but I have certain tasks in my Web App which needs authentication from External Source (Microsoft) every time these tasks get performed by user. I tried setting token lifetime in Azure but [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) says lifetime can not be lesser than 10 minutes.

Note: I can't call signout user because it is not a silent signout.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `prompt=login` parameter in the authentication request. Then the user should be prompted to re-authenticate even if the user has already been authenticated.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-prompt-behavior